# How to delete a file with google drive api without having permission denied?

Tags: node.js, google-api

I have nodejs+typescript project that uses `googleapis` npm package.
I'm using Google Drive v3 and I'm authenticated with service_account json data.

Everything works well for download and upload file, but when I try to delete a file, I get "Insufficient permission" error.

Actually I know why but I would like to know how to bypass it.

Why: because my service_account data is not directly related to my google user account but to a xxx@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com. That I created in the google api console. So I shared a folder to this user and thus can only read and edit but not delete (all the stuff that is shared with the account).

How can I bypass that problem?

Thank you!

Comment: I think you need to be the owner to delete, check [this link](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494892).

Comment: yeah the problem is "When you make someone else the owner of a file, you won’t be able to: Transfer ownership, even back to yourself."

Comment: Then this "someone else" shouldn't be able to delete _your_ files ;) (Joking but it's the spirit they put in this system apparently. And I understand it, for what it's worth.)

Comment: I could give the ownership to this account service, but how could I login in google drive with this service to set ownership back to the original user if needed? I don't have any password

Comment: There should be a way using the [`transferOwnership` property](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/update).